# Translating dynamic content in django templates

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a html template rendered by a view in django. And the template has some dynamic values that the view sends.

Example::

```
{{ text_to_be_translated.brand_name}}
```

The above 'text_to_be_translated.brand_name' is a dictionary with thousands of keys like brand_name, which can hold many values like 'my brand', 'your brand' etc

I am not able to get the above dynamic text translated.

I tried to manually put msgids for the texts in the po file

```
msgid "my brand"
msgstr "カードインフォメーション"
```

But it doesn't get translated.

What am I doing wrong, please help.

Comment: did you try django translation tags, ? more details in https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/1.11/topics/i18n/translation/#internationalization-in-template-code

Comment: you will get your text with `{% trans "my brand" %}`

Comment: I get {% trans "my brand" %} and I get the msgid for the same. But the actual translation does not happen.

Comment: I would suppose it is an config issue. Have you tried any latin languages

Comment: Static Text as in <p>{% trans 'Hello' %}</p> gets translated fine. But if it is dynamically received from a view it doesn't. Example {{ dynamic_text }}. I can translate 'dynamic_text' in the view using the ugettext_lazy() method. But that is a text based on condition. Hope I made it clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just writing so that somebody may benefit.

I solved the problem by writing a template filter and force translating the text in the template using 'django with tag'

**In template.html**

```
{% with card_details_trans=registration_card_details.card_details|template_trans %}
    {% trans card_details_trans %}
{% endwith %}
```

**In Template Tag**

```
@register.filter(name='template_trans')
def template_trans(text):
    try:
        return ugettext(text)
    except:
        return text
```

**Logic**

1. Django doesn't know that contents of a dynamic variable needs to be translated.
2. The *with* tag calculates the translated value from the applied filter and gives the translated output.

Hope it helps. Cheers!!!